# Multivalued Lookup field in infopath form generates errors

Tags: infopath

I get a Value must be integer error when trying to submit a form that includes a multivalued lookup field.

I've tried setting the item to store Title/display Title, and also ID/Title but neither works.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Any way to post a sample? Post a parallel thread on InfoPathDev asking the same question. You will be able to attach the template and put a link to the file attachment on InfoPathDev. Maybe someone there will answer your question first too!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the control to a mutivalue checkbox (instead of Lookup) and it works fine.